# RLExpection: [realsense_drive.launch] is neither a launch file in package [camera_driver] nor is [camera_driver] a launch file name

Tags: ros, robotics, calibration, realsense

I am trying to perform HandEyeCalibration and following
https://github.com/lixiny/handeye-calibration-ros
When I run "roslaunch camera_driver realsense_driver.launch" in Handeye-Calibraion-ROS, I am getting this error:

```
RLExpection: [realsense_drive.launch] is neither a launch file in package [camera_driver] nor is [camera_driver] a launch file name
```

I have checked, intel camera is connected.
Please help

Comment: You haven’t installed the package or haven’t sourced the right setup file

Comment: @BTables Which package and source am I missing? Can you please tell? Thanks

Comment: The handeye-calibration-ros one.

Comment: I have that package, now when I am trying to run ```catkin_make``` under ```Handeye-Calibration-ROS```, it is giving PCL errors ```no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const pcl::PCLPointField' to 'const int&'```

Comment: @BTables I am working on handeyecalibration for a month. Do you know any link that can help me please?

Comment: This is a separate question you should post(with code). If you’re running into cmake errors it will never build and you will never have installed launch files; thus the error you’re question saw.

Comment: Ok, I am building the complete package again and if the pcl error appear again will create another post. Thanks @BTables